# Reboot : Power Down Ubuntu 20.4.2 LTS Problem

Tags: boot, shutdown, reboot

I'm new Ubuntu user , I'm using 20.4.2 version and when I try to power off My Laptop it starts to shut down after that it shows only black screen within message up left says:
Reboot : Power Down

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by this:

## sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

Then just add the following to the booting parameters: acpi=force like this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
After that, save the file and run the command:

## sudo update-grub