# Computer does not shut down properly (Reboot: Power down)

Tags: shutdown

When I turn off my computer, it happens, say one out of two times, that the computer freezes on a black screen displaying "Reboot: Power down" in the top left-hand corner. This forces me to turn it off via the on/off button.

After consulting a few topics on the Internet, I've tried to change some parameters on the grub file, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349414/reboot-power-down-ubuntu-20-4-2-lts-problem), but the problem persists.

What can I do to stop this problem, please?

Thanks in advance

Marethyu