# After Upgrade ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 and my pc not completely poweroff

Tags: upgrade, shutdown, reboot, 23.04, 23.10

After I received ubuntu Upgrade to Ububntu 23.10 and alot of [problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492236/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-23-10-from-23-04-alert-uuid-xxxx-does-not-exist-dropp) happened.
I fixed most of them and the last problem is that when I poweroff my PC it never powers off. the screen and the keyboard and closed but the PC is still running and its fans still running.
The same thing when I restart it never restart.
My PC was working very well before this upgrade.

I also tried to use a live USB with Ubuntu 23.10 burned on it and I found that this issue happens also with the live USB.
I really have no idea what is the problem and I tried to update upgrade and reinstall nvidia-driver but nothing worked for me. I removed the BIOS battery and also reset the CMOS but It didn't work also. This problem occurs only when I run Ubuntu 23.10 and **not** occur with other distros.

I have a Dell Precision Tower 3620.

Here is some part of my syslog file:

```
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606064+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.316137] workingset: timestamp_bits=36 max_order=21 bucket_order=0
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606065+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.316152] zbud: loaded
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606062+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606066+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.316356] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606071+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Started irqbalance.service - irqbalance daemon.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606080+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.316420] fuse: init (API version 7.38)
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606082+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.316553] integrity: Platform Keyring initialized
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606083+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.316555] integrity: Machine keyring initialized
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606084+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.324357] Key type asymmetric registered
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606080+02:00 omar avahi-daemon[937]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 110) and group 'avahi' (GID 116).
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606085+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.324361] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606086+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.324381] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 243)
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606087+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.324440] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606089+02:00 omar systemd[1]: networkd-dispatcher.service - Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd was skipped because no trigger condition checks were met.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606097+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.325060] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 123
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606100+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.325179] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606104+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.325230] efifb: probing for efifb
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606106+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.325247] efifb: showing boot graphics
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606107+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.326305] efifb: framebuffer at 0xd0000000, using 8100k, total 8100k
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606109+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.326307] efifb: mode is 1920x1080x32, linelength=7680, pages=1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606097+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting polkit.service - Authorization Manager...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606119+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.326308] efifb: scrolling: redraw
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606121+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.326309] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606123+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.326348] fbcon: Deferring console take-over
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606125+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.326349] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606123+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting power-profiles-daemon.service - Power Profiles daemon...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606126+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.326981] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606131+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.327003] ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606132+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting rsyslog.service - System Logging Service...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606142+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.327029] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606141+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting secureboot-db.service - Secure Boot updates for DB and DBX...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606145+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.327044] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRB]
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606146+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.327070] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606148+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.327104] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRF]
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606149+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.327992] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606150+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.327994] ACPI: thermal: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (28 C)
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606152+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.328191] thermal LNXTHERM:01: registered as thermal_zone1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606150+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Started snapd.aa-prompt-listener.service - Userspace listener for prompt events.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606160+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.328193] ACPI: thermal: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (30 C)
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606162+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.328277] ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606159+02:00 omar systemd[1]: snapd.core-fixup.service - Automatically repair incorrect owner/permissions on core devices was skipped because no trigger condition checks were met.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606163+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.328279] pstore: Registered erst as persistent store backend
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606164+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.328423] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606166+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.349624] 00:01: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606167+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.353281] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606175+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.357201] tpm_tis 00:0c: 1.2 TPM (device-id 0xFE, rev-id 2)
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606177+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.371615] loop: module loaded
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606178+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.371872] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606179+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.371905] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606181+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.372034] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f03:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606167+02:00 omar systemd[1]: snapd.recovery-chooser-trigger.service - Wait for the Ubuntu Core chooser trigger was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionKernelCommandLine=snapd_recovery_mode).
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606182+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.374704] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606186+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.374714] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606188+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Reached target getty-pre.target - Preparation for Logins.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606209+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.378315] Freeing initrd memory: 55476K
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606212+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.378489] device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606214+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.378501] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606206+02:00 omar systemd[1]: ssl-cert.service - Generate snakeoil SSL keypair was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key).
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606217+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.378557] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.48.0-ioctl (2023-03-01) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606218+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.378586] platform eisa.0: Probing EISA bus 0
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606220+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.378588] platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606224+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon was skipped because no trigger condition checks were met.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606228+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.378590] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606229+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.378591] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606232+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Reached target nss-user-lookup.target - User and Group Name Lookups.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606241+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd-nss.socket: Bound to unit sssd.service, but unit isn't active.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606262+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Dependency failed for sssd-nss.socket - SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606271+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd-nss.socket: Job sssd-nss.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606279+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd-autofs.socket: Bound to unit sssd.service, but unit isn't active.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606287+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Dependency failed for sssd-autofs.socket - SSSD AutoFS Service responder socket.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606295+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd-autofs.socket: Job sssd-autofs.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606315+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd-pac.socket: Bound to unit sssd.service, but unit isn't active.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606324+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Dependency failed for sssd-pac.socket - SSSD PAC Service responder socket.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606332+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd-pac.socket: Job sssd-pac.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606340+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd-pam-priv.socket: Bound to unit sssd.service, but unit isn't active.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606349+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Dependency failed for sssd-pam-priv.socket - SSSD PAM Service responder private socket.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606407+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.379357] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606408+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.392058] NET: Registered PF_INET6 protocol family
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606410+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.399028] Segment Routing with IPv6
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606411+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.399050] In-situ OAM (IOAM) with IPv6
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606409+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Dependency failed for sssd-ssh.socket - SSSD SSH Service responder socket.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606419+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.399070] NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606421+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.399175] Key type dns_resolver registered
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606422+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.399874] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606423+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.399879] IPI shorthand broadcast: enabled
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606425+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.401296] sched_clock: Marking stable (400001595, 429512)->(406404540, -5973433)
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606426+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.401497] registered taskstats version 1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606431+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.402047] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606418+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd-ssh.socket: Job sssd-ssh.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606436+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.402506] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: d958bf91db860e84e483a11e67904e1cf15a98a5'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606438+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.402907] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Live Patch Signing: 14df34d1a87cf37625abec039ef2bf521249b969'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606439+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.403296] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Kernel Module Signing: 88f752e560a1e0737e31163a466ad7b70a850c19'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606441+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.403297] blacklist: Loading compiled-in revocation X.509 certificates
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606442+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.403313] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing: 61482aa2830d0ab2ad5af10b7250da9033ddcef0'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606440+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd-sudo.socket: Bound to unit sssd.service, but unit isn't active.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606450+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.403327] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2017): 242ade75ac4a15e50d50c84b0d45ff3eae707a03'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606452+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.403341] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (ESM 2018): 365188c1d374d6b07c3c8f240f8ef722433d6a8b'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606451+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Dependency failed for sssd-sudo.socket - SSSD Sudo Service responder socket.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606453+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.403353] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2019): c0746fd6c5da3ae827864651ad66ae47fe24b3e8'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606458+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.403365] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2021 v1): a8d54bbb3825cfb94fa13c9f8a594a195c107b8d'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606460+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.403377] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2021 v2): 4cf046892d6fd3c9a5b03f98d845f90851dc6a8c'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606461+02:00 omar systemd[1]: sssd-sudo.socket: Job sssd-sudo.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606468+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.403389] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2021 v3): 100437bb6de6e469b581e61cd66bce3ef4ed53af'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606470+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.403402] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (Ubuntu Core 2019): c1d57b8f6b743f23ee41f4f7ee292f06eecadfb9'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606471+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.405060] Key type .fscrypt registered
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606473+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.405061] Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606470+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting accounts-daemon.service - Accounts Service...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606474+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.405104] pstore: Using crash dump compression: deflate
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606475+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.405284] Key type trusted registered
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606479+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Started cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606486+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.408238] Key type encrypted registered
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606488+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.408241] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606489+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.408539] integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606491+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.408566] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011: a92902398e16c49778cd90f99e4f9ae17c55af53'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606492+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.408567] integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606493+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.408584] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011: 13adbf4309bd82709c8cd54f316ed522988a1bd4'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606505+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.408843] integrity: Revoking X.509 certificate: UEFI:dbx
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606490+02:00 omar dbus-daemon[939]: dbus[939]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606507+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.408865] blacklist: Revoked X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows PCA 2010: d14fa98a0708cef4241898e500fff3d6791d37bc'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606508+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.409812] Loading compiled-in module X.509 certificates
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606510+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.410201] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: d958bf91db860e84e483a11e67904e1cf15a98a5'
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606511+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.410203] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606513+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428819] ima: No architecture policies found
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606511+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting switcheroo-control.service - Switcheroo Control Proxy service...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606521+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428836] evm: Initialising EVM extended attributes:
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606522+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428837] evm: security.selinux
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606524+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428838] evm: security.SMACK64
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606520+02:00 omar cron[972]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606525+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428839] evm: security.SMACK64EXEC
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606526+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428840] evm: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606528+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428840] evm: security.SMACK64MMAP
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606529+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428841] evm: security.apparmor
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606531+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting systemd-logind.service - User Login Management...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606537+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428842] evm: security.ima
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606539+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428842] evm: security.capability
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606540+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.428843] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606541+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.429236] PM:   Magic number: 15:802:38
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606544+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.429294] system 00:0a: hash matches
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606540+02:00 omar systemd[1]: systemd-pcrphase.service - TPM2 PCR Barrier (User) was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/StubPcrKernelImage-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f).
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606552+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.433988] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606554+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.434040] clk: Disabling unused clocks
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606551+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting thermald.service - Thermal Daemon Service...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606555+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.435144] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2036K
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606557+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.435754] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 4788K
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606558+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.464756] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 34816k
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606560+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.465492] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 816K
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606561+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.536693] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606569+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.536695] x86/mm: Checking user space page tables
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606571+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.576739] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606572+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.576744] Run /init as init process
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606573+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.576745]   with arguments:
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606575+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.576746]     /init
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606560+02:00 omar systemd[1]: ua-reboot-cmds.service - Ubuntu Pro reboot cmds was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/private/machine-token.json).
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606576+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.576747]     splash
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606588+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.576748]   with environment:
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606586+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting udisks2.service - Disk Manager...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606589+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.576749]     HOME=/
2023-11-12T20:03:02.60659

1+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.576750]     TERM=linux
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606592+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.576750]     BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-10-generic
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606594+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.726302] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:01: WQBC data block query control method not found
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606596+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.746089] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606595+02:00 omar cron[972]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606608+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.746095] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606613+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.747169] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606604+02:00 omar snapd-aa-prompt-listener[966]: AA Prompt listener not implemented
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606614+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.747207] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000001109810
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606616+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.747845] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606616+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.747850] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606619+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.747854] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606619+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.747903] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.05
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606619+02:00 omar systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606627+02:00 omar systemd[1]: snapd.aa-prompt-listener.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606630+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.747907] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606635+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.747909] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606636+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.747911] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-10-generic xhci-hcd
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606638+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.747912] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606643+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.748234] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606645+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.748269] hub 1-0:1.0: 16 ports detected
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606635+02:00 omar avahi-daemon[937]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606656+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.751921] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.05
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606659+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.751926] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606661+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.751929] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606662+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.751931] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-10-generic xhci-hcd
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606659+02:00 omar avahi-daemon[937]: avahi-daemon 0.8 starting up.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606664+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.751933] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606669+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.752395] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606671+02:00 omar systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606680+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.752418] hub 2-0:1.0: 10 ports detected
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606682+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.755000] usb: port power management may be unreliable
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606680+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Finished grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606684+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.755291] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606686+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.755293] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606688+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.755581] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606690+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.757585] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606689+02:00 omar systemd[1]: Starting grub-initrd-fallback.service - GRUB failed boot detection...
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606692+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.757590] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm led clo only pio slum part ems deso sadm sds apst 
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606706+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.793870] scsi host0: ahci
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606710+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.794222] scsi host1: ahci
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606703+02:00 omar udisksd[981]: udisks daemon version 2.10.1 starting
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606712+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.794582] scsi host2: ahci
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606714+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.794952] scsi host3: ahci
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606716+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.795129] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xef04b000 port 0xef04b100 irq 124
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606718+02:00 omar kernel: [    0.795139] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xef04b000 port 0xef04b180 irq 124
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606716+02:00 omar sbkeysync[986]: Filesystem keystore:
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606737+02:00 omar sbkeysync[986]:   /usr/share/secureboot/updates/dbx/dbxupdate_x64.bin [7085 bytes]
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606747+02:00 omar sbkeysync[986]: firmware keys:
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606755+02:00 omar sbkeysync[986]:   PK:
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606765+02:00 omar sbkeysync[986]:     /DC=com/DC=dell/OU=1/OU=Signing/CN=Dell Inc. UEFI Platform Key
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606773+02:00 omar sbkeysync[986]:   KEK:
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606781+02:00 omar sbkeysync[986]:     /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation KEK CA 2011
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606802+02:00 omar sbkeysync[986]:   db:
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606810+02:00 omar sbkeysync[986]:     /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011
2023-11-12T20:03:02.606819+02:00 omar sbkeysync[986]:     /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011
```

The pc stuck at this:
[image]

### Update

While I was trying to poweroff now I found different error message
[image]

And I do **NOT** have this `dev/sdc4` at all !!

### Update

I run Ubuntu in recovery mode and run command reboot and here what i get
[image]

Comment: I have this also sometimes, maybe 1 out of 10 shutdowns. But the problem existed starting with 23.04 for me.

Comment: Check also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349414/reboot-power-down-ubuntu-20-4-2-lts-problem) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276324/computer-wont-power-off)

Comment: @exactly for me it work properly 1 out of 10 failure shutdowns. I think there's some incompatibility between Ubuntu and PCs

Comment: @pLumo I tried both of them. nothing worked for me :(((

Comment: For me it also doesn't help. `acpi=off` will rather cause problems with the next bootup, leaving me with resolution 1024x768 after it took 5 minutes to boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally solved this problem by removing the RAM and cleaning it very well with some "perfume" :).
And I also cleaned its socket very well.
And surprisingly the issue had disappeared.!!**

*I really have no idea what this is the relation. My PC works very well with any OS except Ubuntu 23.10 even Ubuntu 23.04 is working very well on my PC. but I closed my eyes and tried everything I found online as a solution for this problem. I also tried to clear the CMOS and remove any charge in its circuit. and I also tried to reinstall most of the packages that are related. I also tried to change the APIC attribute in the`/etc/default/grub` file. but only cleaning the ram solved the problem.*